# Restoring oracle database

Tags: oracle

I come from SQL Server and I need to restore a oracle `.bkp` file in my database. I'm using `RMAN` and the path and name for the `.bkp` file is:

```
F:\Oracle Back Ups\Back.bkp
```

The command that I use in `RMAN` is:

```
RMAN> restore controlfile: "F:\Oracle Back Ups\Back.bkp"
```

But it shows an error:

```
ORA-19870 error while restoring backup piece F:\Oracle Back Ups\Back.bkp
ORA-19690 backup piece release 11.2.0.4.0 incompatible with oracle release 11.2.0.2.0
```

I need to know the proper commands to successfully complete this operation.

Note: The guy that provided the back up data gave me two files: One with the extension `.bkp`, and the second with `.ctl`. I don't know how the `.ctl` file is supposed to be used.

I'm using Oracle XE 11.0.0.2.0

Comment: Can you ask whoever provided you with these files to tell you how the backup was generated?  Assuming that RMAN was used to generate this file in the first place, it appears that the source is using 11.2.0.4 in which case you won't be able to restore it to an 11.2.0.2 database.  You'd need to restore it to a database on exactly the same platform running exactly the same version of Oracle.  If the database is small enough to fit in an XE database, I'd wager that you want to ask for an export (a logical backup) rather than a physical backup.

Comment: Ok, so, its the same scenario that in SQL Server when you have a .bak file on 2012 version and tries to restore in DB Engine with 2008 version ??

Comment: Conceptually similar, yes.  I don't know off the top of my head how fiddly SQL Server backup files are at going across minor patch level versions.  But RMAN backups are going to be very version-specific.

Comment: Ok, and there is the correct way to restore a .bkp file in oracle ??

Comment: If you had an 11.2.0.4 database to restore into and assuming that the file that you have was generated via RMAN, yes, there would be a way to restore it.  But we'd generally want to know the RMAN command that was used to produce it.  An export (which would commonly have a .dmp extension) can be restored (within reason) to a different version of the database running on a different platform so it's generally much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Can you copy the 11.2.0.4.0 rman executable from your friend or get and perform a second "dummy" installation of Oracle Database on another temporary computer/server? If so, here's how you can solve it:

Let's say you were able to copy the 11.2.0.4.0 ORACLE_HOME folder from your friend, and called it dbhome_2 (do not replace current, otherwise you can mess up things).

Using the 11.2.0.4.0 rman executable:
- startup instance in nomount and restore controlfile from backup
- mount the db
- restore the archivelogs required (recover database until cancel)

Shutdown the database, and using 11.2.0.2.0 executable:
- restore the control file again, from a 11.2.0.2.0 generated backup
- mount the db
- recover database until cancel
- open database with resetlogs

Hope it helps.